# hasOneThrough relation (Comments -> User -> Rank)

Tags: laravel

This is my first time with the hasOneThrough, and I don't understand very well, I must be missing a hasOne somewhere.

When I post my comments, I would like to be able to make a join with a with on User then Rank.

Here are the relations of the User model:

```
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }
    
    public function rank()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Rank');
    }
```

Here are the relations of the model Rank :

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User');
    }
```

Here are the relations of the model Comment :

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

===> public function rank()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Rank::class, User::class);
    }
```

My method in the controller :

```
$comments = Comment::where('status','=', Comment::STATUS_VISIBLE)
            ->with('user') (working)
            ->with('rank') (not working)
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(10);
```

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: we need the table structure and fields

Comment: oh yes you right sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
$comments = Comment::where('status','=', Comment::STATUS_VISIBLE)
        ->with('user') 
        ->with('user.rank') 
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: That's exactly right, couldn't be simpler, I was looking for too complicated, thanks a lot!!!